# unrecognized selector sent to instance when using UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I am not able to locate the two images and the text box that I placed in my custom cell "GameTableCell.H"... not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

GameTableCell.H:

```
  //

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GameTableCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *GameTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* AwayImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* HomeImage;


@end
```

GameTableCell.m:

```
    //

#import "GameTableCell.h"

@implementation GameTableCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

I have connected the items was well... 
[image: Connecting GameTableCell]

Calling the GameTableCell....is HomePage

HomePage.H:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomePage : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *PendingChal;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *ActiveChal;

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *HomeImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *AwayImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *SportGameInfo;

@end
```

HomePage.m:

```
//

#import "HomePage.h"
#import "PickSport.h"
#import "GameTableCell.h"

@interface HomePage ()

@end

@implementation HomePage
@synthesize ActiveChal,PendingChal;

-(IBAction)makeChallenge:(id)sender{
    PickSport *second = [[PickSport alloc] initWithNibName:@"PickSport" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Arrays for filling table cells
    _HomeImages=@[@"ic_bengals_nfl",@"ic_bengals_nfl",@"ic_bengals_nfl",@"ic_bengals_nfl", ];
    _AwayImages=@[@"ic_bears_nfl",@"ic_bears_nfl",@"ic_bears_nfl",@"ic_bears_nfl", ];
    _SportGameInfo=@[@"7:00pm",@"8:00pm",@"9:00pm",@"10:00pm",];
    [self.PendingChal registerClass: [UITableViewCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GameTableCell"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Set up the table props
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

//number of rows in the table
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // rows eqiv to length of array SportGameinfo
    return _SportGameInfo.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"GameTableCell";
    GameTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

    if(tableView == PendingChal){
        if (!cell) {
            NSLog(@"cell was nil");
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        int row =[indexPath row];
        cell.HomeImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:_HomeImages[row]];
        cell.AwayImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:_AwayImages[row]];
        cell.GameTime.text=_SportGameInfo[row];
    }

    if(tableView == ActiveChal){
        int row =[indexPath row];
        cell.GameTime.text=_SportGameInfo[row];
        cell.HomeImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:_HomeImages[row]];
        cell.AwayImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:_AwayImages[row]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The specific error reads: 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell HomeImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79ee11a0'
*** First throw call stack:

Any help would be appreciated... I feel I'm doing something just slightly wrong (I hope).

Comment: pls add more tags like programming language and other tags related to your query

Comment: u added images using Images.xcassets??? Also add an exception breakpoint

Comment: is the `"cell was nil"` part ever reached? I suggest you dont alloc a `UITableViewCell` but rather a `GameTableCell`

Comment: yes i'm pulling them from xcassettes. Ultimately i will pull from a url I'm attempting to get this "dummy" table running first locally before a venture off into the depths of the internet.

Comment: HI, Can you please do two changes 1) Instead of registering class in 'viewDidLoad', register nib i.e use following method  - (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier    2) instead of - (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier use following method in cellForRowArIndexPath         - (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    NOTE: check properly identifier also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are registering  wrong class

```
 [self.PendingChal registerClass: [UITableViewCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GameTableCell"];
```

should changed like

```
[self.PendingChal registerClass: [GameTableCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GameTableCell"];
```

And please following method in your GameTableCell.m file

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        self = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    return self;
}
```

This resolve your issue. For clear idea  I am adding some more info please go through once 
Basically we have two ways to implement custom cells.

**CASE1)registering class:** we have three steps

**1)register our custom cell class in tableview object like bellow**

```
[self.PendingChal registerClass: [UITableViewCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GameTableCell"];
```

**2)And we need to manually initilize  customcell with specific nib in customcell .m file like bellow.**

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        self = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    return self;
}
```

**3) You need not to check cell value nil in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you will get all references automatically**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"GameTableCell";
    GameTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

//Access all cell properties here.

return cell.
}
```

**CASE2: Register nib.**

```
[self.PendingChal registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"GameTableCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GameTableCell"];
```

and use directly in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like bellow

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"GameTableCell";
        GameTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

    //Access all cell properties here.

    return cell.
    }
```

Finally instead of using

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"GameTableCell";
            GameTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
```

use following method

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"GameTableCell";
                GameTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath
```

];

Note: overRide `customcell.m` file according to this method

Please go through with following link for custom cell integration. you will get clear idea about this. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Now, try and let me know

Comment: I tried this... it gets me through the error. But nothing in my table populates. Additionally i don't get any error that items are Null...

Comment: Hi, can you try    [self.PendingChal registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"GameTableCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]  forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GameTableCell"];
// you xib class name

Comment: Please let me know if above edited my solution does not work. we have one more solution for that

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing this in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if (!cell) {
    NSLog(@"cell was nil");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

with

```
if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
 }
```

It looks like you are initialising the cell as UITableViewCell which doesn't contain reference for HomeImage variable, so you have to load the cell from XIB if dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns cell as nil.

Hope the above solution will resolve your issue.

Comment: hmmmm did not fix the issue. Same issue persists.